# How to integrate AIR with Windows superbar?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, winapi, air, progress-bar

I'm making a sort of batch processing application with Flex and AIR and I want to illustrate the progress of the batch. I'm using `mx:ProgressBar`, but this is not enough for me, I want to see the progress in the Windows superbar, pretty much similar to when I'm copying files.
The only thing I found is [this native extension](https://github.com/daniel-frank/fre-taskbar-progress), but i don't want to use native extensions.

Does AIR provide any API for this?

Comment: Since you're trying to access native functionality, you will _have_ to use native extensions. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to access native functionality, you will have to use native extensions. There's no way around it. commented by RIAStar.

Comment: Well... I think I must admit it; I thought if AIR provides APIs for some native things (for example `sensors.Accelerometer`) then it can provide an API for taskbar progress. Seems like I was wrong.
By the way, [that native extension](https://github.com/daniel-frank/fre-taskbar-progress) works fine.